# Always negative speed iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, location, cllocationmanager

I'm using the delegate method:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
```

To get the current and old location, I used:

```
CLLocation *newLocation = [locations lastObject];
self.currentUserLocation = newLocation;

if(self.oldLocation == nil)
{
    self.oldLocation = newLocation;
    return;
}
```

**EDIT 1:** I can get the old location now.

But I always have a negative speed when I use `[newLocation speed];` = -1

The device used is an iPhone 4s. Do you have an idea ?

Also, for the locationManager, I used kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation and kCLDistanceFilterNone. I can see on the map my current location moving.

**EDIT 2:**

I finally achieve the issue with the speed using this method:

```
- (CLLocationSpeed)speedTravelledFromLocation:(CLLocation*)fromLocation;
{
    NSTimeInterval tInterval = [self.timestamp timeIntervalSinceDate:fromLocation.timestamp];
    double distance = [self distanceFromLocation:fromLocation];
    double speed = (distance / tInterval);
    return speed;
}
```

This method returns the speed calculated from the distance and time deltas between self and fromLocation.

I found this method in this repository: https://github.com/100grams/CoreLocationUtils
Hope it will help someone ;)

**EDIT 3**

Got it! It was because I'm testing on simulator! I tested on a device and the speed using [newLocation speed] is correct!

Thank you for your help.
Regards, 
Lapinou.

Comment: Just a side note, the old location is usually cached, so the first one you get may be one that is relatively wrong from the navigation perspective. I always check a timestamp of the new location and filter for example older then 5 min.

Comment: Ok. I edit my code and using this, I can get my first location which will be my oldLocation. But why my speed is all the time = -1 ?

Comment: See my answer, try different delegate method.

Comment: Oh, sorry. Did not know it is deprecated, still using it.. Show the code where are you checking the speed. It just must work.

Comment: I wrote it in my post: [newLocation speed];, normally return the speed in m/s. But all the time = -1

Comment: I had a negative speed because I used the simulator! Problem solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you expecting the location callback to have 2 or more locations?

This method:

```
(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
```

Usually delivers you just one location, except if for some reason multiple locations arrived before that method was called, but you usually will get just one location.

The problem is that you are assuming that that method gives you your previous location along with the new one, and it's not like that.

Comment: Oh ok! I see now... I gonna try using this so: if(self.oldLocation == nil) self.oldLocation = newLocation; But for the negative speed, do you have an idea ? Thank you anyway! :)

Comment: No idea about that one, sorry

Answer (score 2):

Negative speed usually means you don't have a GPS signal.